# Trimming reaction time data per participant per condition

Tags: r

I have reaction time data an I'm trying to get rid of outliers. My goal is to calculate the standard deviation for each participant in each condition and remove values that are more than 2 SDs above the mean.
My data.frame `data_vfin` looks something like this. There are four conditions and six observations per condition per participant.

```
participant condition   rt
1435157254  I_A        728
1435157254  A_A        752
1435157254  A_S        2771
1435157254  I_S        673
1435157254  I_A        1749
1435157254  A_A        1215
1435157254  A_S        681
1435157254  I_S        488
1435157254  I_A        464
1435157254  A_A        525
1435157254  A_S        517
1435157254  I_S        426
1435157254  I_A        431
1435157254  A_A        453
1435157254  A_S        522
1435157254  I_S        421
1435157254  I_A        432
1435157254  A_A        493
1435157254  A_S        377
1435157254  I_S        425
1435157254  I_A        356
1435157254  A_A        486
1435157254  A_S        369
1435157254  I_S        381
1435157283  A_A        3088
1435157283  I_S        568
1435157283  A_S        488
1435157283  I_A        432
1435157283  A_A        536
1435157283  I_S        456
1435157283  A_S        440
1435157283  I_A        456
1435157283  A_A        1192
1435157283  I_S        344
1435157283  A_S        432
1435157283  I_A        456
1435157283  A_A        449
1435157283  I_S        440
1435157283  A_S        592
1435157283  I_A        448
1435157283  A_A        1136
1435157283  I_S        448
1435157283  A_S        384
1435157283  I_A        472
1435157283  A_A        432
1435157283  I_S        624
1435157283  A_S        464
```

I have been able to trim by either participant or condition using the following code:

```
data_trimmed <- do.call(rbind,by(data_vfin,data_vfin$participant, function(x) x[!abs(scale(x$rt)) > 2,] ))
```

I am however at a loss on how to do it per participant per condition at the same time. I'm pretty new to working with R so any help would be more than welcome.

P.S.: I tried using the `trimr` package which was made for this exact operation but when I try to trim per condition per participant and select "raw" as return type it returns an empty data.frame.

Comment: Grouping by both participant and condition with the data you've provided leads to each group having only 1 value for the `rt` column. When taking the standard deviation of one row, you will always get `NA`. If the data happens to be more than what you're showing here, please add some more rows here.

Comment: There are six observations per condition per participant. I have edited my post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `dplyr` and `magrittr` packages:

```
install.packages(pkgs=c('dplyr','magrittr'))
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)

rt <- structure(list(participant = c(1435157254L, 1435157254L, 1435157254L, 
1435157254L, 1435157254L, 1435157254L, 1435157254L, 1435157254L, 
1435157254L, 1435157254L, 1435157254L, 1435157254L, 1435157254L, 
1435157254L, 1435157254L, 1435157254L, 1435157254L, 1435157254L, 
1435157254L, 1435157254L, 1435157254L, 1435157254L, 1435157254L, 
1435157254L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L, 
1435157283L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L, 
1435157283L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L, 
1435157283L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L, 
1435157283L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L, 1435157283L), condition = structure(c(3L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("A_A", 
"A_S", "I_A", "I_S"), class = "factor"), rt = c(728L, 752L, 2771L, 
673L, 1749L, 1215L, 681L, 488L, 464L, 525L, 517L, 426L, 431L, 
453L, 522L, 421L, 432L, 493L, 377L, 425L, 356L, 486L, 369L, 381L, 
3088L, 568L, 488L, 432L, 536L, 456L, 440L, 456L, 1192L, 344L, 
432L, 456L, 449L, 440L, 592L, 448L, 1136L, 448L, 384L, 472L, 
432L, 624L, 464L)), .Names = c("participant", "condition", "rt"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -47L))

trimmed <- rt %>% group_by(participant, condition) %>% 
           mutate(avg = mean(rt), stdev = sd(rt)) %>% 
           filter(rt <= 2*stdev+avg) %>% 
           select(participant, condition, rt) %>% 
           as.data.frame()
```

Only one row was dropped. `rt` has 47 rows and `trimmed` has 46 rows

#### What's going on here?

You first group by both participant and condition, and for each group you get its standard deviation (`stdev`) and mean (`avg`) by `mutating` the data.frame. With those values of mean and standard deviation, you filter (i.e. keep) any value of the column `rt` where `rt <= 2*stdev + avg`. Finally, select your original columns. Once that's done, you can convert your output into a native R data.frame.